# C - return pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have to write a function with the signature

```
 int *greater (int n[], int length, int value)
```

that returns a pointer to an array containing the elements in n[] that are greater than a value. The array returned must be exactly the length to hold the values greater than value and have no unused elements.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int k=0, v[100];

int * greater(int n[], int length, int value)
{
    for (int i=0; i<length-1; i++)
        if (n[i]>value)
        {
            v[k]=n[i];
            k++;
        }
    int *p=v;
    return p;
}
int main ()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p=greater (a,5,3);
    int *end; end=v+k;
    while (p<=end)
    {
        printf ("%i ", *p);
        p++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that p will only hold the value of 4, therefore it will print 4 0, instead of 4 5. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `i<length-1` --> `i<length` and `while (p<=end)` --> `while (p<end)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY incorporated the same in my answer. thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve your issue, do not use a *global* array(`v[100];`). Instead,

1. define a pointer inside `greater()`
2. allocate memory dynamically using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).
3. resize the memory as per the requirement using [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)
4. return the pointer.

In the lights of the comment from Mr. **@alk**, you can get the number of elements in the array using the global variable `k`.

Note: once you're done using the memory, don't forget to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the pointer from `main()`.

BTW, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`

---

EDIT:

Also, for the logical part, as mentioned in the comments by Mr. **@BLUEPIXY** and **@karma_geek**, please note

1. change the looping condition to `for (int i=0; i<length; i++)`
2. Change the `while` loop to `while (p<end)`

Comment: So what would the caller do with a pointer to an array's 1st element, where s/he does not know the number of the array's elements? Calling `free()` is the only possible action, isn't it?

Comment: @alk sir, IMHO, that can be resolved using `k` in this case, am I right?

Comment: Hu, I fully missed this. Yes, assuming the `k` would be around (still global, very ugly) this would do.

Comment: Please touch your answer, so I can revoke the downvote.

Comment: @alk yeah, updated my answer with a hint in regard to your comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 changes in addition to the ones already mentioned:

Iterate the `for loop` till `<length`, as `<legnth-1` would not cover the entire array.

```
int * greater(int n[], int length, int value)
{
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (n[i]>value)
        {
            v[k]=n[i];
            k++;  // increment
        }
    int *p=v;
    return p;
}
```

Also, change the formula for end. This is because in the function, where the increment occurs, `k=0` would change as: `k=1` for `4 > 3`, then `k=2` for `5 > 3`. Now,

```
end = v + k ;
```

would result in `end = v + 2` when instead we wanted 1 lesser value.

```
int *end; end=v+k-1;
```

[Code with correct output](http://ideone.com/fVYq6B)

Comment: You approach does not meet this requirement: "*The array returned must be exactly the length to hold the values greater than value and have no unused elements.*" Also it would not work for inut arrays larger then `v`.

Answer (score 0):

As the specs do not require to return the size of the target array, allocating a new array inside the fucntion make the pointer returned quiet useless as the caller does not know which elements (if any) are valid.

So the only sane approach would be to **not** allocate memory for the target, to not even use a second array. This also is not required by the specs, so you might like to take following approach

1. Sort the input.
2. Find the 1st element greater then the give threshold, by simply looping over the result from 1..
3. Return the pointer to the element found in 2.

Example:

```
#include <qsort.h>

int cmp(const void * pv1, const void * pv2)
{
  int i1 = *((int *) pv1);
  int i2 = *((int *) pv2);

  return (i1 - i2);
}

int * greater(int n[], int length, int value)
{
  qsort(n, sizeof *n, length, cmp);

  while (0 < length)
  {
    --length;
    if (n[length] > value)
    {      
      break;
    }
  }

  return n + length + 1;
}
```

The only req/

> array returned must be exactly the length to hold the values greater than valu

is met.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your search function to return the number of elements found in a pointer parameter. Allocate the results array within the function, minimize the number of possible allocations in the function, shrink the results array before returning.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *
greater(
        const int const n[],
        const size_t n_elem,
        const int threshold,
        size_t *n_greater
        )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t n_found = 0;
    size_t n_allocated = 0;
    int *ret = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < n_elem; i += 1) {
        if (n[i] > threshold) {
            n_found += 1;
            if (n_found > n_allocated) {
                size_t new_size = (n_allocated < (n_elem / 2))
                                ? 2 * n_found
                                : n_elem
                ;
                int *tmp = realloc(ret, new_size * sizeof(*tmp));
                if (!tmp) {
                    fputs("Failed to allocate memory", stderr);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                n_allocated = new_size;
                ret = tmp;
            }
            ret[n_found - 1] = n[i];
        }
    }
    if (n_allocated > n_found) {
        int *tmp = realloc(ret, n_found * sizeof(*tmp));
        if (!tmp) {
            fputs("Failed to shrink result array", stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ret = tmp;
    }
    *n_greater = n_found;
    return ret;
}

int main (void)
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3,7,6,5,5,0,-1,7};
    size_t n_greater_than_three = 0;
    size_t i =0;
    int *p = greater(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), 3, &n_greater_than_three);

    for (i = 0; i < n_greater_than_three; i += 1) {
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    }

    free(p);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> greater.exe
4                                             
5                                             
7                                             
6                                             
5                                             
5                                             
7
```